# Coloring an image in matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to know how to color a rectangle created in matlab itself by the following code:

```
rectangle = 255*ones(100,100);
line1 = zeros(1,70);
line2 = zeros(1,40);
rectangle(1,1:70) = line1;
rectangle(40,1:70) = line1;
rectangle(1:40,1) = line2;
rectangle(1:40,70) = line2;
figure(1)
imshow(rectangle);
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why not rectangle(1:40,1:70) = zeros(40,70) ?

Comment: To create the rectangle? If yes, it's because I need to make more things in the image, not only the rectangle.
But if you mean, to create a colored rectangle, what I actually need is put any color (RGB) inside the rectangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest looking into matlabs built in graphics objects rather than making them from scratch; this will save you **significant** time.  This is a different method though - you are not manipulating matrices, but using built in objects that matlab has already specified.  You can look [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rectangle.html) for more info, but here's an example that might be relevant:

```
figure;
hold all;
xlim([0,1]);
ylim([0,1]);
set(gca,'visible','off');
rectangle('Position',[0,0,.5,.5],'FaceColor',[1,0,0]);
rectangle('Position',[.5,.5,.2,.2],'FaceColor',[0,0,1],'EdgeColor',[0,0,0],'Linewidth',4,'Linestyle','--');
```

resulting picture:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that way it's really much better, though I think perhaps will not be accepted by my teacher. Anyway, I'll probably use this method.

Comment: I tried, but I received a message that it is necessary to have at least 15 reputation for it. As I am new to this site I do not have it yet :(

Comment: @anon0909 I tried it in my Saturn Fiddle and it works! https://saturnapi.com/vpartition/colored-rectangles

Comment: @anon0909 Thanks, I'm one of the devs! If you want to connect, email me art@saturnapi.com